# Is there a standard library equivalent of memmove?

Tags: c++, memcpy, idioms, memmove, stdcopy

The standard library offers `std::copy`, which can be seen as a generalization/generification of C's `memcpy()`. It also maintains the requirement of `memcpy()`, for the range [`first`, `last`) to be disjoint from the range [`d_first` , `d_first + std::distance(first, last)`); otherwise we have undefined behavior.

My question: Is there a generic version of `std::memmove` (i.e. which doesn't make that requirement and would typically be implemented using a temporary buffer)? If not, how come?

Comment: [std::copy_backward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward)?

Comment: `std::copy` isn't really a generalization of `std::memcpy`. They have *very* different semantic. As in `std::copy` copying object while `std::memcpy` does a byte-wise copying.

Comment: @bolov `memmove` is safe no matter which direction the overlap is in. `std::copy_backward` is not.

Answer (score 5):

C++ doesn't have drop in replacements for `memcpy` and `memmove`.

For non-overlapping ranges usually `std::copy` is used, but `std::copy_backwards` can also be used.

For overlapping ranges you need to use `std::copy` or `std::copy_backwards` depending on the nature of the overlap.

Also for copy-expensive objects [`std::move` (`<algorithm>`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) and [`std::move_backward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward) respectively can be used instead if the original objects don't need to keep their value.

[std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

> ```
> template< class InputIt, class OutputIt >
> OutputIt copy( InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first );
> ```
>
> Copies the elements in the range, defined by [first, last), to another
> range beginning at d_first.
>
> Copies all elements in the range [first, last) starting from first and
> proceeding to last - 1. The behavior is undefined if d_first is within
> the range [first, last). In this case, std::copy_backward may be used
> instead.
>
> **Notes**
> When copying overlapping ranges, std::copy is appropriate when copying
> to the left (beginning of the destination range is outside the source
> range) while std::copy_backward is appropriate when copying to the
> right (end of the destination range is outside the source range).

[std::copy_backward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward)

> ```
> template< class BidirIt1, class BidirIt2 >
> BidirIt2 copy_backward( BidirIt1 first, BidirIt1 last, BidirIt2 d_last );
> ```
>
> Copies the elements from the range, defined by [first, last), to
> another range ending at d_last. The elements are copied in reverse
> order (the last element is copied first), but their relative order is
> preserved.
>
> The behavior is undefined if d_last is within (first, last]. std::copy
> must be used instead of std::copy_backward in that case.
>
> **Notes**
>  When copying overlapping ranges, std::copy is appropriate when copying to the left (beginning of the destination
> range is outside the source range) while std::copy_backward is
> appropriate when copying to the right (end of the destination range is
> outside the source range).